# Add level to existing nested dictionary(tree)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary(tree) with given values.

```
nodes = [{'id': 20, 'child': [{'id': 21, 'child': [{'id': 23, 'child': [{'id': 31}]}, {'id': 24}]}, {'id': 22}]}, {'id': 25, 'child': [{'id': 32}]}]
```

I like to update it with new key and value(level:integer) in each dicitonary.
The level should specify the nested order.(Shown as below)

```
nodes = [{'id': 20, 'child': [{'id': 21, 'child': [{'id': 23, 'child': [{'id': 31}], 'level': 2}, {'id': 24}], 'level': 1}, {'id': 22}], 'level': 0}, {'id': 25, 'child': [{'id': 32}], 'level': 3}]
```

I have tried to get the solution by using recursion. But due to for loop, this solution is incorrect

```
counter=0
def abc(list):
    global counter
    for i in list:
        if 'level' not in list:
            if 'child' in i:
                i.update(level=counter)
                counter += 1
                abc(i['child'])
    return list
```

Comment: why is it wrong? Show what your code is returning and what is the expected return

Comment: if I understand what you want, adding a `counter-=1` just before the `return list` would make the level correct. But I don't know exactly what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to achieve that:

```
nodes = [{'id': 20, 'child': [{'id': 21, 'child': [{'id': 23, 'child': [{'id': 31}]}, {'id': 24}]}, {'id': 22}]}, {'id': 25, 'child': [{'id': 32}]}]

def set_level(obj, level=0):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        # If the function is called on a list, we call the function on each element
        return [set_level(el) for el in obj]
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        # If the function in called on a dict, we add the level
        obj['level'] = level
        if "child" in obj:
            # If the object have a sublevel, we call the function
            # for this sublevel
            obj["child"] = [set_level(c, level=level+1) for c in obj["child"]]
        return obj


nodes = set_level(nodes)
```

This will be the output:

```
[
  {
    "child": [
      {
        "child": [
          {
            "child": [
              {
                "id": 31,
                "level": 3
              }
            ],
            "id": 23,
            "level": 2
          },
          {
            "id": 24,
            "level": 2
          }
        ],
        "id": 21,
        "level": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "level": 1
      }
    ],
    "id": 20,
    "level": 0
  },
  {
    "child": [
      {
        "id": 32,
        "level": 1
      }
    ],
    "id": 25,
    "level": 0
  }
]
```